# Example of 2 Inverse function

Tags: calculus, functions

Im trying to find 2 functions $f,g$ such that $f $ and $ g $ both **no**t **linear**, and $ f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} $ 1-1 and onto, such that $ f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)=x,\thinspace\thinspace\:g\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=x $.

(f is the inverse function of g).

There exists such functions?

Comment: For a more exotic example, how about $f(x)=g(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=0\\0&\text{if }x=1\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: I encourage you to try to come up with your own, an important skill in maths is being creative.  Really, *any* bijective $f$ will do (*apart from lines passing through origin*)... and there are a *lot* of choices available to you there.

Comment: Might be informative to prove that inverse of bijection is a bijection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $f(x)=x^3$, $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$